# Exact semantics of getRowData()?

Tags: java, jsf, datatable

First time using JSF, and I'm sort of confused about how `getRowData()` works. All I found while searching around the internet is that it returns the "currently selected row" in a data table, but I couldn't find out how it decides which row is the selected one. For example, I have this code for a data table:

JSP:

```
  <h:dataTable value="#{backing_student.eligibleCoursesList}" var="cdto"
                     binding="#{backing_student.eligibleCoursesDataTable}"
                     id="eligibleCoursesDataTable" rules="all" frame="box"
                     border="2">
  <%-- 
            oracle-jdev-comment:Faces.RI.DT.Class.Key:hu.elte.pgy2.BACNAAI.UranEJB.CourseDTO
          --%>
    <h:column>
      <f:facet name="header">
        <h:outputText value="Kurzuskód"
                      binding="#{backing_student.outputText7}"
                      id="outputText7"/>
      </f:facet>
      <h:outputText value="#{cdto.cid}"/>
    </h:column>
    <!-- couple more plain text columns like the above -->
    </h:column>
    <h:column>
      <h:commandButton value="Felvétel"
                       actionListener="#{backing_student.addSelfToCourseListener}"/>
    </h:column>
  </h:dataTable>
```

Backing bean:

```
public class BackingStudent {
    private HtmlDataTable eligibleCoursesDataTable;
    private List<CourseDTO> eligibleCoursesList;

    // ...

    public void addSelfToCourseListener(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        HtmlCommandButton thisButton = (HtmlCommandButton)actionEvent.getComponent();
        CourseDTO cdto = (CourseDTO)(eligibleCoursesDataTable.getRowData());
        thisButton.setValue(cdto.getCid());
    }
}
```

This makes it so that whenever I click the button in whichever row, the text of all buttons changes to the value in the first column of that row. How exactly does `getRowData()` know which row to fetch from the table?

Bonus question: why does every button's text change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JSF tags cause a component tree to be built in memory. For example, the `dataTable` tag is backed by a [UIData](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html) instance (of which `HtmlDataTable` is a subclass). The role of `UIData` is to iterate over a [DataModel](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html). For each phase of the [JSF lifecycle](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/), it will do something like this:

```
//not the real code
for(int i=0; i<model.getRowCount(); i++) {
  model.setRowIndex(i);
  Object row = model.getRowData();
  externalContext.getRequestMap().put(var, row);
  //invoke phase-specific action
  externalContext.getRequestMap().remove(var);
}
```

In your case, the `var="cdto"`, which is why any controls that use EL to resolve to the row bean will get the correct value.

When the component tree is built, `UIData` does not add another child control per row. It uses one set of controls and changes the underlying model data. Although the `UIData` [performs some actions to preserve child state](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIData.html#setRowIndex%28int%29), it will not do so (by default) for instances of [HtmlCommandButton](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlCommandButton.html) because it does not implement [EditableValueHolder](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/EditableValueHolder.html).

To fix this issue, use an EL expression to bind the value to your model (probably some row bean property).

*Note: you can generally avoid having to write code where you have to import any `javax.faces...` classes into your model beans, but you have to put a bit of thought into your model design.*

Comment: So: the client/browser detects whenever I click a row in the table, and calls `setRowIndex()` on the `UIData` object representing that table. Then whenever I make a call to the backing bean via a HTTP request, the row index (along with all other table data) is supplied to the `HtmlDataTable` on the server side in phase 4, and at the next phase when the call is actually executed, `getDataRow()` will already have the right index. Did I get that right?

Comment: @sus: The client/browser doesn't set anything in Java/JSF code. It just sends as usual request parameters on form submit (use Firebug/Fiddler to see them). The index is in the button's parameter name. JSF checks the request parameters and sets the index accordingly during apply request values phase.

Comment: @BalusC: wait, I'm confused again. I just added a column of checkboxes to my table (not bound to any bean property) and set up a `valueChangeListener` for them that stores `getRowData()` in a temporary variable. When I click the button, the listener gets called on each checkbox, and each of them get their own row from `getRowData()`, but the POST's only parameters are the form, the button and the viewState. How do the different invocations of `getRowData()` in the listeners all get their own value if a) it wasn't sent, and b) listeners are called after phase 1 is over?

Comment: @sus: The `valueChangeListener` is a different story. It just get invoked for each row where the newly submitted value is different from the initial value, as roughly outlined in McDowell's answer. My comment was regarding the action event.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on a row, the component calls `DataModel.setRowIndex()`, which sets the index of the clicked row. `DataModel.getRowData()` retrieves the data of the row that `DataModel.getRowIndex()` refers to.